# How to call a client side method from the server using socket.io

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, flask

I am using flask-socketio for the server and have the following code to call a client function from the server. Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there a better way

Server

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    sleep(5)
    emit('my response', {'data': 'myFunction', 'parameter': 2})
```

Client

```
socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    window[msg.data]({parameter1 : msg.parameter});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The server should never try to explicitly call any function on the client.** Client and server are different applications that "talk" to each other through requests, but I would consider bad practice having a server that knows the names of functions in the client, how the response will be handled by the client, or how the visual interface works. Similarly, it would be really bad if the client knew about the server specific implementation, and tells it which database to use, for instance.

This is just simple [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Also, read about Client-Server domain separation. Anyhow, I don't know about your specific application, but **let's get to a practical example**:

Let's assume your app is a modified version of stack overflow. When a user upvotes an answer, the server is notified, and the client app has to change the height of a bar for that certain user (according to the new number of points) on a page that shows all users...

Following how your implementation design today, this is what would happen:

Server

```
emit('new-points', {
     'data': 'IncreaseBarHeight',
     'parameter': '10px',
     'user': '3476'
})
```

Client

```
socket.on('new-points', function(msg) {
    window[msg.data]({height : msg.parameter});
    //this would trigger global IncreaseBarHeight('10px', msg.user)
}
```

So the client *has some knowledge* about the interface, it knows that there's a bar in the UI and that the height should be increased. If I decide to change the UI and have only the number instead of a bar, I would have to re-implement the server as well. They are too coupled.

**This is a much better approach:**

Server

```
emit('new-points', {'points': 3560, 'user': '8376'})
```

Client

```
socket.on('new-points', function(msg) {
    SetBarHeight(msg.points, msg.user); //set height based on total points
}
```

The server doesn't know how the client will use the information, and therefore they are not coupled. I can change the UI representation of the points without having to modify the server. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. This is very useful.